# What should I do with my freshly opened LLC in California after I've moved?

Tags: united-states, taxes, limited-liability-company, california

I recently opened LLC in California in Dec 2016. Now I moved to Washington state and I got a full time job there as well.

What am I supposed to do with it? 
Make it as LLC in WA state somehow? Keep it running in California? 
Should I close it somehow right now? Will it look suspicious that I just spent $800 on legalzoom fees and close it right away?

I planned originally to do a business in California but things changed and I don't know what to do with it.

Comment: I did not want to type an answer, but here's a link that'll help. 

http://smallbusiness.findlaw.com/incorporation-and-legal-structures/conducting-business-as-a-corporation-or-an-llc-out-of-state.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no reason to keep the California LLC if you don't intend to do business in California.  If you'll have sales in California then you'll need to keep it and file taxes accordingly for those sales.  You can just as easily form a new LLC in Washington state and even keep the same name (if it's available in Washington, that is).

Keeping the California LLC just creates paperwork for whatever regulatory filings California will require for no purpose at all.

As for your question about it looking suspicious that you just set up an LLC and then are shutting it down, nobody's going to care, to be honest.  As with your situation, plans change, so it isn't really all that unusual.  If you're concerned the government will say something, don't.

Comment: An extra reason for closing CA and opening WA is that CA has high fees and a lot of paperwork.